# MySQL Automatic renaming resultset

Tags: mysql

[image]While testing the project for backend verification and entry I am opening around 30-40 resultsets in mysql Query browser. Even I enter the data from the backend and verify in the UI. Now I am manual renaming the resultset to the tablename. Since there are lots of tables (around 700) and I need to frequently switch between the tables . The renaming task is time consuming . Is there any way to automatically rename the resultset as the selected table name.

Comment: rename can be in different ways, can you explain better or show some screenshot or code?

Comment: As in the image . I want to open lots of resultsets. Instead of manually renaming the resultsets .Is there any other way so that the table in the select query should be theResultset name.

Comment: you can alter the column name or create functions or procedures to display result set as you want